# Tampermonkey: Load Other Tampermonkey-Script

Tags: tampermonkey

I've run into a situation where I need code to run in isolated mode on one page and on the main page on another. So what I have in mind now is rather than store that utility-stuff on a local file to have that in Tampermonkey (should avoid accidentally deleting or moving that local file and making it unreachable). In other words Tampermonkey's installed user scripts lists three files (utility, site A, site B).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         utility
// @namespace    http://sjngm/
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

// not even sure how to do this here, probably like
const Utility = {
  func: () => { ... }
};
```

Now that has to be loaded somehow:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         site A
// @namespace    http://sjngm/
// @match        http*://site-a.com/*
// @grant        GM_xmlhttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
  'use strict';

  // I guess the magic now goes here somehow
  GM_xmlhttpRequest({
    method: "GET",
    url: "utility", // <= that's probably the main issue
    onload: (e) => {
      console.log(e.responseText);
    }
  });

})();
```

The above doesn't work as it loads "utility" based on the URL of the page if I get this right. So I somehow need to reference into Tampermonkey somehow. Is that even possible?

Comment: See: [Make `@require` able to point to other userscripts](https://github.com/Tampermonkey/tampermonkey/issues/853). This is not possible at the moment.

Comment: Alright, apologies for jumping in... Clearly I did not understand. Best wishes with your project.